# Actionscript 3 - Reading String from PHP echo

Tags: php, actionscript-3, string, variables

i have a php script that print with echo this:
'&string="tom,dick,harry"'

and i need to put the "tom,dick,harry" in an actionscript string, that i have to split in an array. I'm having problems reading the php output, i'm using the URLLoader and TheURLVariables Classes in this way

```
        var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("ip/directory/script.php");
        var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();           

        function onLoaded(event:Event):void {
            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables( event.target.data );
            modelli = variables.string.split(",");
            caricaColori(modelli[0]);
        }

        myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
        myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        myLoader.load(myRequest);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem that you have? I feel like you forgot to mention the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought that you got problem with URLVariables, I still not totally understand this yet

```
function onLoaded(event:Event):void {
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables( event.target.data );
        modelli = variables.string.split(",");
        caricaColori(modelli[0]);
    }
```

why do you need to store it into a URLVariables instance? Why don't parse it directly. If you are afraid of the "&string=", you don't need to echo it on PHP side, or can slice it out on Actionscript side.

```
modelli = event.target.data.split(",");
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, i solved the problem changing the echo format like you suggested

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a variable name that isn't reserved might help. `string` seems like a bad choice.

Comment: Keyword is case sensitive. String is the keyword not string. So bad choice yes but shouldn't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
// in php change
echo '&string="tom,dick,harry"'
// to 
echo "tom,dick,harry"

// in actionscript change
function onLoaded(event:Event):void {
  var str:String = event.target.data;
  modelli = str.split(",");
  caricaColori(modelli[0]);
}
```

If you want to add more variables and whatever, I would suggest turning the php response into an xml file. URLVariables should be used to  **SEND** data to the server not for parsing a server response.
[LOOK HERE](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLVariables.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
   function onLoaded(event:Event):void {
        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables( event.target.data );
        modelli = variables.string.split(",");
        caricaColori(modelli[0]);
    }
```

Your problem is that you're loading the variables into a URLVariables container, and then trying to call a string function on it. I would do it this way instead:

```
function onLoaded(event:Event):void {
    //load data as a string
    var variables:String = event.target.data;

    //make a new array
    var modelli:Array = new Array();
    modelli = variables.split(",");

    //possibly pop the array
    modelli.pop(); //pop off the last empty element of array

    caricaColori(modelli[0]);
 }
```

There's also a good chance that when you load this PHP data, you'll need to pop() the last element off of the array because it will be an empty string.